# how to replace part of a bigger string using T-SQL REPLACE

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a table that contains names. The names vary in length with ampersands between them ('&') I need to replace every '&' with 'and' while keeping the other part of the string. I'm not understanding how to do this.

My failed attempt: two example rows in table:

```
ROW1: Mr & Mrs Smith
ROW2: Sam & Sally Smart

SELECT REPLACE(.,' & ',' and ');
```

Hoping for result of:

```
Mr and Mrs Smith
Sam and Sally Smart
```

Advice?

Comment: Where's the name of the column you are replacing in?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the information in the same column that I'm looking in.

Comment: You need to **name** it in your `REPLACE()` call.

Comment: so if my table name is NAMES and column name is MAILING_NAME what would that look like? SELECT REPLACE(MAILING_NAME, ' & ',' and ');

Comment: Excellent! That does not actually change the content of the field, just shows me the results correctly, right? So if I want field updated too would it look like UPDATE <TABLE> SET REPLACE(MAILING_NAME, ' & ',' and ')

Comment: Yes, you will need to use the correct syntax for `UPDATE` statement. The one you wrote wouldn't compile.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: `Update <TABLE> Set <COLUMN> = REPLACE(<COLUMN>, ' & ',' and ');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
SELECT REPLACE(Column_Name,'&','and') 
FROM Table_Name
```